# Strange Label AutoSize issue on TableLayoutPanel resize

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background:**

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` placed in a `UserControl`, which then is placed in `SplitContainer`. Rows are added programmatically. `TableLayoutPanel` is anchored `Top|Left|Right`, so after rows are added, its height is recalculated and it expands downward.

Inside the `TableLayoutPanel`, there are two columns. The size of the first column is `Absolute`, the size of the second column is set to `AutoSize`.

In every cell, there is a `Label`. All labels in the second column are defined as follows:

```
  Label vName = new Label();
  vName.AutoSize = true;
  vName.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
  vName.Margin = new Padding(3);
  vName.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
  vName.Name = "controlName";
  vName.Text = "Some text here";
  vName.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(vName_DoubleClick);
  vName.Dock = DockStyle.None;
```

**The problem:**

Usually, everything works all right, labels resize and everything, except for one strange scenario:

1. The text of the label is something like `"immoballizes the device (33.33%)"`, width of `TableLauoutPanel`'s second column is set exactly, so all text is shown in one line.
2. Splitter distance changes by one pixel and the `UserControl` is resized: width decreases, so the label should resize, and the text in a label should wrap.
3. **The label is not resized, and the second line of text isn't shown**, it also probably doesn't wrap (there would be a change in the text location in the label if it did).
4. Splitter distance changes by one pixel again, and the `UserControl` is resized: the width decreases further.
5. The label resizes all right and all text is shown, wrapped.

The same thing happens when the `TableLayoutPanel`'s width increases, but always only if there is a difference of one pixel (between wrapping/not wrapping text).

Also, changing `Dock` and/or `Anchor` and/or `BorderStyle` properties of labels doesn't work (I probably tried all possible combinations...)

This picture illustrates the issue a little:

[image]

Comment: I notice you've set `Anchor` and left `Dock = DockStyle.None`...is there a reason?  Dock should help with this.

Comment: I tried this in the beginning. Makes no difference.

Comment: You are giving the layout engine conflicting instructions.  You say that the label should automatically resize itself with AutoSize = true.  But then also say it should observe the container's size with the Anchor property.  This tends to cause bi-stable layout since there are *two* solutions to the layout request.  Probably more in your case because you also made the column autosize.  You'll need to get rid of this ambiguity.  Start by zapping the anchor.

Comment: You said your `TableLayoutPanel` is placed in a `UserControl`, so how is it placed? `Anchor` is not enough, what about `Dock` and its position in the `UserControl`? I think a screen shot of your whole form is better to describe your problem.

Comment: @Hans Passant, zapping the anchor doesn't help. I tried that already. The funny thing is it works perfectly fine in all situations except when differenc between wrapping and not wrapping text is exactly 1 pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a label issue: when autosizing, it wasn't measuring text correctly and sometimes there was a one pixel difference. I've found a strange workaround, though, if someone knows something better please enlighten me.

This way text in my labels wraps correctly every time and everything is autosized properly:

```
void tableLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float fWidth = tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths()[1];
            foreach (Control ctr in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctr is Label && ctr.Name.Contains("vName_"))
                {
                    // -7 for margins
                    Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(ctr.Text, ctr.Font, new Size((int)fWidth - 7,1000),
                        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter 
                        | TextFormatFlags.Left 
                        | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding 
                        | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
                    if(!ctr.MaximumSize.Equals(s))
                        ctr.MaximumSize = new Size(s.Width, s.Height);
                }
            }
        }
```